# EXT4 Filesystem seems to have disappeared

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem, ext4

I previously had an LVM consisting of a few different drives, including two 4TB Seagate USB's.
I migrated my data off the drives. Copy -> Shrink -> Copy -> Shrink

Once the drive was removed I formatted it to EXT4 and put some data back on it.
I did this to about 7 drives.
4 Internal and 3 USB externals.

One of the seagate externals was full from a copy -> shrink. Meaning I formatted it, Mounted it, and put around 3.5TB of data on it. The other 4TB drive should be empty.
The data was there and read/writeable.

On a possibly unrelated note I had got greyhole working and was attempting to mount a samba share locally. I had to restart. So I shutdown and came back to the project a week later (it's been off the entire time)

I tired mounting one of the 4TB externals.

```
~$ sudo mount /dev/sdg external
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

I then run parted:

```
~$ sudo parted -l
...
Model: Seagate Backup+ Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      24.6kB  4001GB  4001GB               primary


Model: Seagate Backup+ Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdh: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags   
 1      24.6kB  4001GB  4001GB               primary
```

The complete output can be seen here: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/D8MZ86Wp)

So as you can see the filesystem tags are now empty. While the other internal drives are fine and a WD passport USB drive is fine too.

I tried mounting the drive again using this tutorial on dirty EXT4's: [How to Mount Dirty EXT4 File Systems](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/06/14/digital-forensics-mounting-dirty-ext4-filesystems) but this just gave me similar errors to normal mounting.

```
:~$ sudo mount -o loop,ro,noexec,noload /dev/sdh external
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
:~$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,ro,noexec,noload /dev/sdh external
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

:~$ dmesg | tail -l
[ 1938.343779] EXT3-fs (loop0): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev loop0.
[ 1938.343875] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1938.344016] FAT-fs (loop0): Unrecognized mount option "noload" or missing value
[ 1942.733970] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

Thank you all for your time.

Edit: after running fsck:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdg

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is because the EXT4 FS is dev/sdg1 and not dev/sdg.